# Using sql:query with CUSTOMER table in Derby's sample database in Netbeans default installation

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, glassfish, derby

I use Netbeans 8.0.2 on Windows. I wrote an example JSP page

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello, World!</h2>
        <sql:query var="allRows" dataSource="jdbc/sample">
            SELECT name, city, state FROM APP.customer
        </sql:query>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach var="currentRow" items="${allRows.rows}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>"${currentRow.name}"</td>
                        <td>"${currentRow.city}", "${currentRow.state}"</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

but if I execute this page, I get

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: 
            SELECT name, city, state FROM APP.customer
        : Table/view 'APP.CUSTOMER' is not exist.
```

sample database is a demo Derby database. I use GlassFish Server 4.1, JDK 7, Java EE 7. All these are in the default installation of Netbeans. I use default settings of GlassFish Server.

I see sample database connection at Services tab. It is jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample. I see this url in SamplePool connection pool properties of GlassFish. This connection pool is used in jdbc/sample JDBC resource. APP.CUSTOMER table is exist in sample database.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what is wrong but try the following:

- copy **derbyclient.jar** from `glassfish4/javadb/lib` to `glassfish4/glassfish/lib/endorsed`
- restart Glassfish
- change your code to the following:

  ```
  <sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource"
                     url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample"
                     user="app"  password="app"/>
  <sql:query var="allRows" dataSource="${snapshot}">
      SELECT name, city, state FROM APP.customer
  </sql:query>
  ```

To play with a basic example this should be sufficient, but you may not want to use it in production.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works. Now I will try to understand what I need to further customize GlassFish.